# In a UITextView the 'accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors' property has the opposite effect

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview

In my UITextView I was trying to troubleshoot the text view inverting colors when the Smart Invert option is switched on by the user (*Settings/Accessibility/Display & Text Size/Smart Invert*). The original reason for the issue was because an image in an NSTextAttachment would invert colors and basically be a negative image of itself.  In trying to correct this, I set the accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors to true, as stated by the Apple documentation (that view and all its subviews will ignore the setting).  However, this seems to increase the problem.

In the code below, setting the property equal to true will actually show the color inversion, while leaving that line of code out will suppress the color inversion. Can someone provide insight as to why it seems to behave in the opposite manner for me? I assume I am missing something but I don't have any idea what that might be.  Thanks all!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myTextView = UITextView(frame: .zero)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(myTextView)
        myTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        myTextView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        myTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        myTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true

        myTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        myTextView.accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem that `NSTextAttachment`s in a `UITextView` are inverted. They are not inverted for me when `accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors = false`, and are inverted when `accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors = true`. Perhaps setting it to true just does the opposite of whatever the system wants to do?

Comment: Yeah, strange behavior. Thank you for checking Sweeper.